# Concatenate 2 Data Frames

Tags: python

Hi I have 2 data frames a and b. a  contains a lot of columns including the id. b contains some ids and counts for those ids. I want to concatenate a and b such that for all the ids in a  that are in b, the counts are join and for the rest there should be 0s.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: sample=pd.merge(a,b,on='id',how='outer')